# How to drag image to "trash can" and remove that single image

Tags: javascript, html, image, drag-and-drop

http://jsfiddle.net/838gD/

how do I drag the image to the second box and then to the trash can 
and delete that very image from the second div
link to my jsfiddle is above

```
<head>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev)
{
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
   var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
   ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="startBox">
<img id="drag1" src="http://www.hayspost.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Wichita-State-Logo.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
</div>
<br>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<img src="http://images.iskysoft.com/data-recovery-mac/mac-trash.jpg" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="trash" draggable="false"/>
</body>
```

Comment: We require Fiddle users to post their *actual code* here in the question, and provide the Fiddle as a backup.  Don't just link to a Fiddle, in other words.  Paste your code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to detect when an element is dropped on the trash and remove the original node.  However, since this is all based on IDs, it'll delete the original image from the startBox first and then delete the image you want on the second attempt.

I'd advise either generating unique IDs for each clone or target nodes a different way.

**EDIT:** Update example with generation of new ID using a timestamp.

```
function drop(ev)
{
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");

    var clone = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
    clone.id = clone.id + (new Date()).getMilliseconds();
    ev.target.appendChild(clone);

    if (ev.target == document.getElementById("trash")) {
        var img = document.getElementById(data);
        img.parentNode.removeChild(img); 
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show me how to generate a unique id for each new img and vall it to delete it.

Comment: @user3354230 Sure thing, example is updated. If this is suitable, would you mind marking this accepted?